# Confluence Ruby

Tags: ruby, confluence

Hi guys this is the script im using : i got this off the site : http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DISC/Confluence4r

I keep getting this error

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/xmlrpc/client.rb:549:in `do_rpc': HTTP-Error: 302 Moved Temporarily (RuntimeError)
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/xmlrpc/client.rb:420:in `call2'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/xmlrpc/client.rb:410:in `call'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/xmlrpc/client.rb:617:in `method_missing'
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL you supplied to that script is probably not the one your server is serving Confluence on. There's usually a redirection like `confluence => confluence.domain.com`, that's why the HTTP 302 "error" (it's not a real error, it's a redirection) occurs.

The simplest way to solve this is to supply the correct URL to the script.

A more future proof way to solve would be rescuing from the HTTP error and use the redirect URL as the server's URL and try again.